# Python Selenium title contains certain words by xpath and jump to next page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to **scrape** and click some links with the title contain certain words, using python selenium, find element by xpath. Get all links from the first page to the last page whose title contains 'certain word'.

but somehow it not working now. (just opening the link and returns nothing)

Please find my code here

Thank you in advance!

```
driver.get('http://www.csisc.cn/zbscbzw/isinbm/index_list_code.shtml')
while True:
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="sibian"]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[contains(@title, '资本')]')]
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        # do sth
        driver.back()
    if(len(links)< 20):
        break
    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text("")
        next_page.click()
    except:
          print('No more pages')
          break
```

Comment: It is because the element you are trying to fetch is NOT present on the current page `//td[text()='[01-20]']` . This is sorted by date in desc order.

Comment: you can search with this `//a[contains(@title, '资本')]` your code should work `links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title, '资本')]")]`

Comment: Hi KunduK thanks! I can see why the code with date cannot work, but returns nothing with your code neither, same as when I use ('//*[@class="sibian"]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[contains(@title, '资本')]'), just frozen in the first page and won't jump to next page

Comment: Try with this xpath "/html/body/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a"

Comment: @cathy please [edit] your question and mentioned expected output as well. Your logic is not clear with infinite loop?? Are you trying to get links for specific text from all pages, If so you need to change the logic then.

Comment: Hi Fabix, thank you, I tried with "/html/body/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[contains(@title, '资本')]", but still just open the page, returns nothing and won't go to next page to search

Comment: Hi KunduK, I edit my question and I want return all links with title contains certain word from the first page to last, thanks!

Comment: //table[2]//a[contains(@title,'资本')] does return 2.

Comment: Thanks Arundeep, but it only return results in the first page, but I want it jump to next page and continuing search to the last page, is that possible?

Comment: Just while true and then proceed to click the next button in a web driver wait.

Comment: I use my code with while true, but only return results in first page, it's good if I remove the title contains condition, but I want the specific links...so